# Inno - how to address the setup window title?

Tags: inno-setup

how can I address this text from the code?
[image]r.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it by the [`Caption`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.Caption) property of the [`WizardForm`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TWizardForm), e.g.:

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.Caption := 'Hi, I''m the installer!';
end;
```

Comment: `procedure 10X;

begin

  WizardForm.Caption := 'Thank U TLama!';

end;`